# analytical solution of BVP and IVP of allen cahn steady state equation

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

The steady state of Allen Cahn equation is $u_{xx}+u-u^3=0$. There's work on solving it as an IVP or BVP under various conditions (most common ones may be heteroclinic solutions) but it's hard to find a paper/book summarizing all these together. In this question, I'm looking for some links/references/books of the **analytic** solution of the IVP and that of the BVP under Dirichlet, Neumann, periodic and mixed of all the above BCs.

Answer (score 3):

You might see this called an [unforced, undamped Duffing equation](http://scholarpedia.org/article/Duffing_oscillator#The_unforced_system).  The general solution can be written using a Jacobi elliptic function

$$u \! \left(x \right) = 
c_{2}  \sqrt{\frac{2}{1+c_{2}^{2}}}\, \mathrm{sn}\! \left(\left. \frac{x-c_1}{\sqrt{1+c_2^2}}\right| c_{2} \right)
$$

Note that the special case $c_{2} = 1$ simplifies to $\tanh((x-c_1)/\sqrt{2})$.

Comment: thanks very much Prof Israel. I'm interested in references about the equation you typed and whatnot! The duffing one you posted is about the double well potential that's **upside down** of that of the Allen Cahn, where $\alpha$<0.

Comment: If sn refers to the elliptic function as defined in ["Handbook of Elliptic Integrals for Engineers and Scientists"](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-65138-0) I believe the equation is similar but not exactly one dimensional allen-cahn. Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems like 

$$sn_{xx}(x|c_2) = - sn([1 + c_2^2] - 2 c_2^2 sn^2)$$

Comment: $\text{sn}_{xx}(x\mid c) = - (1+c^2)\;\text{sn}(x \mid c) + 2 c^2\; \text{sn}(x \mid c)^3$.

Comment: This is using the Gradshteyn & Ryzhik convention, where the parameter is the modulus of the elliptic function.  A different convention, used in Abramowitz and Stegun, is to use the square of the modulus as the parameter.

Comment: @JMK right, unforced, undamped Duffing equation in this answer is not exactly Allen Cahn, as mentioned in my 1st comment

Comment: Unforced undamped Duffing is $\ddot {u} + \beta u + \alpha u^3 = 0$.
Yours is the case $\beta = 1$, $\alpha = -1$.